# Azure Key Vault reference in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-container-registry

I'm currently deploying a docker container to an Azure App Service slot.

I'm using a Linux based app service (App Service Plan S1) and the container is hosted in an Azure Container Registry.

I've configured the required DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_* settings for the app service.

For the server password I'm using a key vault reference (@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=my-vault;SecretName=my-secret)). I've created a managed identity for the app service slot and assigned the GET secret permission in the key vault.
The app settings also show that it is a valid reference:

[Successful key vault reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YdZz.png)

However when I then try to browse to the website I get an error message in the logs stating that the pull request on ACR is unauthorized.

[App Service log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP3JA.png)

```
2022-01-24T09:21:33.589Z INFO  - Pulling image: ******.azurecr.io/******:33819
2022-01-24T09:21:33.730Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://******.azurecr.io/v2/******/manifests/33819: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}
2022-01-24T09:21:33.740Z ERROR - Pull image threw Exception: Input string was not in a correct format.
2022-01-24T09:21:33.747Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: ******.azurecr.io/******:33819
2022-01-24T09:21:33.870Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://******.azurecr.io/v2/******/manifests/33819: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}
2022-01-24T09:21:33.872Z WARN  - Image pull failed. Defaulting to local copy if present.
```

When I replace the DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD value with the actual password the app service is able to successfully pull the container and start the website.

Any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: hi there Bas van der Kruijssen, and welcome to stack overflow. Can I make a suggestion? Your question would be better if you copy and paste the information in text form, instead of using screenshots. It helps readability, indexability, etc.

Comment: Hi @VinceBowdren, thanks for the tip. I've updated my post with the error message. I left the screenshot of the keyvault reference as this is a visual reference that the key is correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

> When I replace the DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD value with the
> actual password the app service is able to successfully pull the
> container and start the website.

As your Container Registry does not have the access to the Azure Key Vault secrets, you are getting pull request on ACR is unauthorized error

You can assign System-Assigned managed identity to your Azure Container Registry and assign the GET secret permission in the key vault

Then you would be able to pull the container and start the website using the key vault reference only

Comment: Shouldn't the read access come from the app service? The keyvault reference is in the application settings of the app service and I would think that that is the managed identity that would be used to get the keyvault secret. That is also what the documentation states: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#granting-your-app-access-to-key-vault

Comment: But the key vault secret is also used by Azure container registry