# How do I access the Key Vault using CATALINA_OPTS in Azure Web App Configuration

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault, tomcat9

My Azure Web App (running on Tomcat9) successfully connects to the Azure SQL database by having the following in `META-INF/context.xml`

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" initialSize="30"
            maxActive="100" validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationQueryTimeout="1000"
          testOnBorrow="true"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=myDatabase;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;loginTimeout=10;user=myuser@myserver;password=${dbPassword}"
            />
```

And having the following `CATALINA_OPTS` application setting in the WebApps Configuration

```
-Ddbpassword=<my password>
```

I want to upgrade my security, so I added a secret in the Key Vault called `DB-PASSWORD` and changed the `CATALINA_OPTS` application setting in the WebApps Configuration as follows

`-Ddbpassword=@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://thekeyvaulttest.vault.azure.net/secrets/DB-PASSWORD/)`

I used this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli) from Microsoft.

However the server failed to start, saying
`/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: eval: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("`

The WebApp has permission to read secrets from the Key Vault. This does not seem to be an authentication issue such as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70800363/azure-key-vault-reference-in-azure-app-service)

The Java code to read context.xml is as follows:

```
public final class DBConnection {

    private static DataSource ds = null;
    private static DBConnection instance = null;
    
    private DBConnection() throws NamingException {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
    }

    public static synchronized DBConnection getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            try {
                instance = new DBConnection();
            } 
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        return con;
    }

    public void returnConnection(Connection con) {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        
        
        return;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide complete code along with app setting?

Comment: I added the Java code to access context.xml. Not sure what you mean by app setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround that works is to use `BasicDataSource` instead of `DataSource` and load the parameters in Java. This bypasses the need for defining the connection in context.xml completely.

```
 String keyVaultUrl = "https://thekeyvaulttest.vault.azure.net/";
 SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
             .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
             .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
             .buildClient();
 ds=new BasicDataSource();
 String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=myDatabase;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;loginTimeout=10;";
 String username = "myuser@myserver";
 String password = secretClient.getSecret("DB-PASSWORD").getValue();
            
 ds.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
 ds.setUrl(url);
 ds.setMaxTotal(100);
 ds.setUsername(username);
 ds.setPassword(password);
 ds.setInitialSize(30);
 ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
 ds.setTestOnBorrow(true);
```